# Transforming a list

Tags: python, list

I have a list like that :

```
[['0', '10'], ['0', '11'], ['0', '12'], ['1', '10'], ['1', '11']]
```

How can i group the elements in the list, for example like above?

```
['0': ['10','11','12']],['1': ['10','11']]
```

Comment: Did you mean to have ['1','11'] as the last item in the list?

Comment: @FarukSahin panpa yes, i edited it

Comment: Is the order of keys (`0` and `1`) in the result important?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

iterate - put into dictionary.

```
d = {}
l = [['0', '10'], ['0', '11'], ['0', '12'], ['1', '10'], ['1', '11']]
for p in l:
    if p[0] in d:
        d[p[0]].append(p[1])
    else:
        d[p[0]] = [p[1]]

>>> d
{'1': ['10', '11'], '0': ['10', '11', '12']}
```

using [defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects):

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
l = [['0', '10'], ['0', '11'], ['0', '12'], ['1', '10'], ['1', '11']]
for p in l:
    d[p[0]].append(p[1])
```

one-liner: using [dict comprehension](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) (a little wasteful, but no imports and requires 2.7+)

```
>>> dd = {key: [i[1] for i in l if i[0] == key] for (key, value) in l}
>>> dd
{'1': ['10', '11'], '0': ['10', '11', '12']}
```

Comment: this one-liner will work in python 2.6 as well as 2.7 : `dict((key,[i[1] for i in l if i[0] == key]) for (key, value) in l)`, though `groupby()` based solution is much better here.

Answer (score 5):

You could use [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
import collections

l = [['0', '10'], ['0', '11'], ['0', '12'], ['1', '10'], ['1', '11']]

d = collections.defaultdict(list)
for k, v in l:
    d[k].append(v)
print(d)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `dict.setdefault()`:

```
In [16]: lis=[['0', '10'], ['0', '11'], ['0', '12'], ['1', '10'], ['1', '11']]

In [17]: dic={}

In [18]: for x,y in lis:
   ....:     dic.setdefault(x,[]).append(y)
   ....:     

In [19]: dic
Out[19]: {'0': ['10', '11', '12'], '1': ['10', '11']}
```

and for your list even [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) will also work fine:

```
In [39]: from operator import itemgetter

In [40]: from itertools import groupby

In [34]: lis=[['0', '10'], ['0', '11'], ['0', '12'], ['1', '10'], ['1', '11']]

In [35]: {k:[x[1] for x in g] for k,g in groupby(lis,key=itemgetter(0))}
Out[35]: {'0': ['10', '11', '12'], '1': ['10', '11']}
```